# how to create custom Inlined subflows in corda like CollectSignaturesFlow/SignTransactionFlow

Tags: java, kotlin, corda

I am trying to understand the **Inlined subflows** by looking into the source code and corda documentation of **CollectSignaturesFlow/SignTransactionFlow** .
can anybody tell me how collectsignature subflow calls the signTxnFlow on the otherside (in the source code)? If you could give some reference it will be great help for writing some custom pairs.

Answer (score 0):

An inlined subflow is simply a flow that is not annotated with `@InitiatingFlow`. It inherits the version number and flow context of the flow that invokes it.

In terms of `CollectSignaturesFlow/SignTransactionFlow`:

- You'll see that to collect each counterparty's signature, the `CollectSignaturesFlow` repeatedly subflows into `CollectSignatureFlow`
- The counterparty is supposed to register their own responder flow that subclasses `SignTransactionFlow` and is initiated by the flow that called `CollectSignaturesFlow` as a subflow

Here is an example:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val signTransactionFlow = object : SignTransactionFlow(otherPartyFlow) {
            override fun checkTransaction(stx: SignedTransaction) = requireThat {
                val output = stx.tx.outputs.single().data
                "This must be an IOU transaction." using (output is IOUState)
                val iou = output as IOUState
                "I won't accept IOUs with a value over 100." using (iou.value <= 100)
            }
        }

        return subFlow(signTransactionFlow)
    }
}
```

We force the user to override `SignTransactionFlow` to ensure they add their own checking for the transactions they are signing.

Comment: thanks ! but Still my question How do i know SignTransactionFlow is supposed to be registered on other side from source code of CollectSignatureFlow perspective . If you can show me the line of code that says it will call SignTransactionFlow

Comment: You don't register inlined flows like `SignTransactionFlow`. They exist as part of the overarching flow. So a call to `send` or `receive` in a `SignTransactionFlow` behaves like a `send` or `receive` of the flow that invoked it as a subflow.